# Boost::bind problem binding overloaded operator

Tags: boost, operator-overloading, bind, threadpool

I've a class with [] operator overloaded. I also have a thread to start...
How can I bind [] to the thread?

I tried this:

`threadpool.schedule( bind( static_cast< MyClass (MyClass::*)(const MyClass &arg )>( &MyClass::operator[]), arg ) )`

but VS2008 says:

error C2664:

```
'boost::threadpool::thread_pool::schedule': cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::_bi::bind_t' to 'const boost::function0 &'
```

How can i resolve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide `MyClass` code ?

Answer (score 1):

That looks wrong. Your member function still accepts one argument. So you need a placeholder, or you forgot to bind `this`

```
threadpool.schedule( bind( 
  static_cast< MyClass (MyClass::*)(const MyClass &arg )>(&MyClass::operator[]), 
  this, arg ) )
```

An `operator[]` that accepts its class type looks a bit weird though. Here is an example how it should look for a "usual" subscript operator

```
threadpool.schedule( bind(
  static_cast< MyClass (MyClass::*)(std::size_t)>(&MyClass::operator[]), this, index ) 
);
```